# Create flexible grid getting data from map

Tags: java, wicket

I'm trying create flexible DataGrid. I have xls/xlsx parser which save tables headers to collection and save data to map with key(column counter) and value(some data), Box.class contains this map and it has @Bindable annotation. In the result have to create grid with any data.

```
@Bindable
public class Box implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String valueStr;
    private ExcelType excelType;
    private Double valueDouble;
    private Money money;
    private HashMap<Integer, Object> mapData;

    public Box(){
       mapData = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public HashMap<Integer, Object> getMapData() {
       return mapData;
    }


    public void setMapData(HashMap<Integer, Object> mapData) {
      this.mapData = mapData;
    }

    public Double getValueDouble(){
      return valueDouble;
    }

    public String getValueStr() {
     return valueStr;
    }

    public ExcelType getExcelType() {
      return excelType;
    }

    public Money getMoney(){
      return money;
    }

    public void setValueStr(String valueStr) {
     this.valueStr = valueStr;
    }

    public void setExcelType(ExcelType excelType) {
      this.excelType = excelType;
    }

    public void setValueDouble(Double valueDouble) {
      this.valueDouble = valueDouble;
    }

   public void setMoney(Money money) {
     this.money = money;
   }

   public enum ExcelType{
    STRING, BIGDECIMAL, INTEGER, NUMERIC, MONEY;
 }
```

Result table

```
public class ResultTable extends WebPage {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   private List<Box> listBox;
   private List<String> headers;


   public ResultTable(List<Box> listBox, List<String> headers) {
     super();
     this.listBox = listBox;
     this.headers = headers;
   }

   @Override
   protected void onInitialize() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onInitialize();

    BoxBinding bb = new BoxBinding();
    ListDataProvider<Box> listDataProvider = new ListDataProvider<Box>(listBox);
    List<IGridColumn<Box, Box, String>> cols = new ArrayList<>();

    HashMapBinding<Integer,Object> map = bb.mapData();

    int columnCounter = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)  {  
    //how to get object from map which in BoxBinding??
      cols.add(new PropertyColumn<Box, Box, String, String>(new Model<String>(headers.get(i)),
                    map.get().get(columnCounter).toString()));//<---- NULLPOINTER!!!
      columnCounter++;      
    }
    DataGrid<IDataSource<Box>, Box,String> grid = new DefaultDataGrid("grid",
            new DataProviderAdapter(listDataProvider), cols);
    add(grid);
}
```

}

When I'm trying add new column with header(name column) and put there reference on Object from map which in BoxBinding I have Nullpointer, because at initialization time there is no map object and no any object in it, data appears after page render.
But when I'm using simple field all is ok.

```
BoxBinding bb = new BoxBinding();
    ListDataProvider<Box> listDataProvider = new ListDataProvider<Box>(listBox);
    List<IGridColumn<Box, Box, String>> cols = new ArrayList<>();

    cols.add(new PropertyColumn<Box, Box, String, String>(new Model<String>("name"), bb.valueStr().getPath()));
    cols.add(new PropertyColumn<Box, Box, String, String>(new Model<String>("age"), bb.valueDouble().getPath()));
    cols.add(new PropertyColumn<Box, Box, String, String>(new Model<String>("money"),
            bb.money().getPath().toString()));
    DataGrid<IDataSource<Box>, Box, String> grid = new DefaultDataGrid("grid",
            new DataProviderAdapter(listDataProvider), cols);
```

How can i put reference in gridcolumn non-existent object from map? I suppose I was understandable. Wicket is old framework not a lot of examples in network(

Answer (score 0):

`map.get().get(columnCounter).toString()` - this is plain Java! No Wicket knowledge is needed to see that it might break at several points!

What is HashMapBinding ?

Why do you expect that calling `.get()` on it will return non-null in all cases ?

Why do you expect that calling `.get(columnCounter)` will be non-null as well ?

Solution: Split this line into several ones and add checks that the result of the last call is not null, e.g. `if (mapGetResult != null) {...}`.

If you use Java8 then you might get advantage of the new java.util.Map methods like `getOrDefault()`, `compute()`, `computeIfAbsent()`, etc.

Comment: HashMapBinding is one of ways  within i tried get map with data. Before digging i thought that grid works like repeaters or dataview, where you just have to set path to your data and columngrid will get this data at runtime. But columngrid sets reference to variable with getPath() method at Initialize time and only after this it iterates over listDataProvider and gets from object